# Change Gboard microphone input

Tags: 8.0-oreo, gboard, google-voice, google-voice-actions, google-pixel-2

[[image]

[image]
[image]

So when I clicked the microphone button on my Gboard, Pixel 2, it used to come up as pictures 1&2.
Now, this changed today, when I click the microphone, the keyboard goes away, and screenshot #3 is what comes up.

I know that this is extremely similar to [Is it possible to trigger Gboard's voice-typing without switching keyboards?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224089/is-it-possible-to-trigger-gboards-voice-typing-without-switching-keyboards).
But I added screenshots to illustrate, and frankly, this issue is irritating me way more than it should, I don't even know why. Probably because it changed *poof* with no warning, rhyme or reason.

Comment: Based on experimenting on my Nexus 5, it looks like you're switching the keyboard to "Google voice typing" instead, a different keyboard app than Gboard. Can you try accessing the system's setting for the virtual keyboard and check if "Goggle voice typing" is enabled?

Comment: So if I disable Google voice typing the regular little microphone is gone. And I want to keep my mini-mic.